# How to use magrittr piping with multi-argument functions?

Tags: r, magrittr

For single argument functions, it is reasonably trivial to translate "standard" R code to the [`magrittr`](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr) pipe style.

```
mean(rnorm(100))
```

becomes

```
rnorm(100) %>% mean
```

For multi-argument functions, it isn't clear to me what the best way to proceed is.  There are two cases.

Firstly, the case when additional arguments are constants.  In this case, you can create an anonymous function which changes the constant values.  For example:

```
mean(rnorm(100), trim = 0.5)
```

becomes

```
rnorm(100) %>% (function(x) mean(x, trim = 0.5))
```

Secondly, the case where multiple vector arguments are required.  In this case, you can combine inputs into a list, and create an anonymous function that operates on list elements.

```
cor(rnorm(100), runif(100))
```

becomes

```
list(x = rnorm(100), y = runif(100)) %>% (function(l) with(l, cor(x, y)))
```

In both cases my solutions seem clunky enough that I feel like I'm missing a better way to do this.  How should I pipe multiple arguments to functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the pipeR package the solution for the cor-example would be:

pipeR:

```
set.seed(123)
rnorm(100) %>>% cor(runif(100))

[1] 0.05564807
```

margrittr:

```
set.seed(123)
rnorm(100) %>% cor(y = runif(100))

[1] 0.05564807
```

There is an excellent pipeR tutorial [available](http://renkun.me/pipeR-tutorial/) from the autor of the package. There's not much of a difference in this case :-)

Answer (score 11):

In v. 1.5 there are two options:

```
list(x = rnorm(100), y = runif(100)) %$% cor(x, y)
```

Which is essemtially the same as

```
list(x = rnorm(100), y = runif(100)) %>% with(cor(x, y)) # you could also do this earlier
```

Or

```
list(x = rnorm(100), y = runif(100)) %>% { cor(.$x, .$y) }
```

The `{` pair creates a lambda (unary function) on the fly so you don't have to do the whole `(function(x) { ... })` thing.

As a side note, the `inset` and `inset2` aliases can be used to "pick up" values in a pipeline, in e.g. lists.

Comment: Oh my god, you have no idea how long I have been wishing there was a shorter syntax for anonymous functions in R...

Answer (score 2):

The first problem can be solved by `%>%`'s clever evaluation.  The clunky solution simplifies to

```
rnorm(100) %>% mean(trim = 0.5)
```

The second problem can be simplified in a similar way, though it isn't clear if this is the "best" solution.

```
rnorm(100) %>% cor(y = runif(100))
```

Comment: I tendto look to `pipeR` in cases like this.  It's partly what idiom each user is more comfortable with, so I recommend folks play around with both packages for a while to see which helps them more.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Interesting.  So how does a `pipeR` solution look?

Comment: Well, I'm not expert at either pipe tool yet, but what I like about `pipeR` is that you can use a "." in multiple places on the right-hand side to represent the output of the left-hand side.